# Atlassian SDK won't start specified product

Tags: sdk, jira, jira-plugin

I'm trying to get a JIRA addon running on my local machine for test purposes. I'm executing this command:

```
e:\repositories\jira-addon>atlas-run-standalone --product jira
Executing: "D:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven\bin\mvn.bat" com.atlassian.maven.plugins:maven-amps-plugin:4.2.1:run-standalone -gs D:\atlassian-plugin-sdk\apache-maven/conf/settings.xml --product jira
Unable to parse command line options: Unrecognized option: --product
```

I'm quite sure it used to work before. I'm not sure what the problem is, but we recently upgraded from jira 5 to jira 6.

Any suggestions on how to get the Atlassian SDK running my plugin again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in a specific version of the Atlassian Plugin SDK (version 4.2.1). It was fixed in 4.2.2. To upgrade to the fixed version, you can just run the `atlas-update` command.

---

(the bug report and fix is here: https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/AMPS-995)

Answer (score 0):

When I use `atlas-run-standalone -Dproduct="jira"`, it does work. This still doesn't explain why the SDK doesn't behave according to specification, though.